# Cannot call Parse.Promise._continueWhile

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, parsing, promise

I've tried the conditional promise loop as follow but it never enter to the second function. I did search around but have no solution yet. Please give me some idea about this. Thanks

P/S: this api comes from api for JS in parseplatform.org

```
Parse.Promise._continueWhile( function() {
  query.find().then( function( results ) {
     queryResults = results;
     logger.log('info', 'I can enter this function');
     return queryResults.length != 0;
  });
  }, function() {
     logger.log('info', 'Cannot enter this function');
     var a = new Parse.Promise();
     a.resolve();
     return a;
  });
```

Comment: you say you can't call `Parse.Promise._continueWhile` ... where would such a thing come from? perhaps mention the library http://parseplatform.org/ somewhere in your question :p

Comment: Yeah, that's right, it's in parseplatform.org, api for JS. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything in the first function, so Parse would have no idea of knowing that it needs to continue.

However, even if you add `return`, you'll still have a problem because the first function has to return a result synchronously, not with a promise. You need to perform your asynchronous actions in the second function:

```
var shouldContinue = true;

Parse.Promise._continueWhile( function() {
  return shouldContinue;
}, function() {
  return query.find().then( function( results ) {
    logger.log('info', 'I can enter this function');

    // use results

    shouldContinue = (results.length != 0);
  });
});
```